# Mysql Filter data using Timestamp stored in table

Tags: mysql

I have stored bill date in `timestamp` in mysql.

In reports, i get from and to date in `dd-mm-YYYY` format.In query I have used like this,

```
WHERE  (from_unixtime(bill.bill_date,"%d-%m-%Y")) >='06-04-2019' AND (from_unixtime(bill.bill_date,"%d-%m-%Y")) <= '30-04-2019'
```

But the data 06/05/2019 also fetched. I don't know why it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're surprised that the value '06-05-2019' is greater than '06-04-2019'?

You can't use inequalities like `>=` with dates in %d-%m-%Y format. MySQL prefers the format %Y-%m-%d, and that's the format it assumes when checking sort order for dates, and for inequality comparisons.

You should use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` with no format argument. Then it will return dates in %Y-%m-%d format, which does support inequality comparisons.

Use date literals in %Y-%m-%d format.

I would write your expression like this:

```
WHERE from_unixtime(bill.bill_date) BETWEEN '2019-04-06' AND '2019-04-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `between` instead?

```sql
WHERE (from_unixtime(bill.bill_date,"%d-%m-%Y")) BETWEEN '06-04-2019' AND '30-04-2019'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying format for the column but not for the condition values. Try:

```
WHERE  (from_unixtime(bill.bill_date,"%d-%m-%Y")) >=STR_TO_DATE('06-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y') AND (from_unixtime(bill.bill_date,"%d-%m-%Y")) <= STR_TO_DATE('30-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

or better yet:

```
WHERE (from_unixtime(bill.bill_date,'%Y-%m-%d')) BETWEEN '2019-04-06' AND '2019-04-30'
```